# Using 1 event handler for multiple templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have been using the usual Blaze [Template.events](https://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.5/api/templates.html#Template-events) way of handling events. Currently I have many events that are the same across multiple templates.

I was curious if anyone knew a way to **handle events for multiple templates without having to use multiple Template.events calls** for each different template.

(you could just write one event handler to apply to multiple templates).

If I switched to Meteor-React I think this could be done but I would rather not do that at the moment.

Comment: I've done this in the past with [dynamic templates](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic). Or you can define common functions that the various event handlers invoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this package called `meteor-body-events`

`meteor add gwendall:body-events`

Their git page is this: https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-body-events

I'd used it in my previous project and it works as expected, although, now I see that the project is no longer maintained. I believe it should still work as expected.

Example from their git page:

```
Template.body.events({
  "click .btn": function(e, data, tpl) {
    // e -> jquery event
    // data -> Blaze data context of the DOM element triggering the event handler
    // tpl -> the parent template instance for the target element
  }
})
```

So basically, you tag the event listener to the body once, and it will work for all templates.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thanks. Hopefully it doesn't slow down stuff a lot for some reason. Thanks